# how to crawl twitter for specific tweets?

Tags: java, twitter, web-crawler, text-mining

I am doing a project on social media framework for banking sector and as a part of it i am trying to collect all the tweets from twitter which contains certain keywords.So do i have to write a crawler all on my own from the scratch or are there any available tools for this.If i have to write my own crawler,is writing in JAVA advisable?and any links which will guide me how to get started with coding a crawler.I dont want the code but only guidelines on how to code it. And any good links about how crawler works etc would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to request for twitter developer API to get the twitter tweets. But I am
> not sure any restriction or limit on getting data.

https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php

Comment: any tutorials on how to use it?